# Custom menu creation in django-xadmin dashboard using django-xadmin-extras

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-admin

I have an app named **Foo**. [Django-xadmin](https://github.com/sshwsfc/xadmin) automatically creates menu under an app based on the models defined. I want to create a Custom menu with my custom view. Here is my Custom admin view written in **adminx.py** -

```
from xadmin.views import CommAdminView

class TestAdminView(CommAdminView):
    form = TestForm
    app_config = FooConfigForCustomMenu

    def get_context(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(TestAdminView, self).get_context(*args, **kwargs)
        form = TestForm()
        ctx["form"] = form

        return ctx

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, "app/app.html", self.get_context()) 

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Do some stuff
        return render(request, "link to another template")

# Registration
xadmin.site.register_view(r"^foo-test/$", TestAdminView, name="foo-test")
```

Here, i have inherited from xadmin's [CommAdminView](http://xadmin.readthedocs.io/en/docs-chinese/views_api.html#xadmin.views.CommAdminView). **FooConfigForCustomMenu** is written according to [Django-xadmin-extras](https://github.com/jneight/django-xadmin-extras) documentation in **apps.py** like this -

```
from xadmin_extras.apps import AdminAppMixin

class FooConfigForCustomMenu(AdminAppMixin):
    name = 'test'
    verbose_name = 'test'
    icon = 'chart'

    def init_menu(self):
        return [{'url': r"^foo-test/$", 'icon': 'bolt',
        'title': 'Test for foo', 'order': '', 'perm': None}]

APP_CONFIG = FooConfigForCustomMenu()
```

But there is no menu named **test** appearing in xadmin under **Foo** app. What am i doing wrong here ? I am stuck here for hours. The form is initiated like this in **forms.py** by inheriting **Form** class of django.forms -

```
from django.forms import Form

class TestForm(Form):
    # Initiation of form fields
```